# Iterate through a number of txt files and find patterns

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a simple script to iterate through a number of text files within a pre-defined folder and try to find patterns using dataframe.  However I got the below error on the bolded line.  Could anyone have a look?  thanks a lot!

OSError: Initializing from file failed

```
for files in os.listdir(outPath):
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
           for f in os.listdir(outPath):
               **df1=pd.read_csv(f,header=None)**
               for line in df1:
                   df1=df1[~df1[0].str.contains(pattern1)]
                   df2=df1[~df1[0].str.contains(pattern2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob. Also, please don't loop over the dataframe, it will be slower.

```
import glob
flist = glob.glob(outPath + '/*.txt')
for fn in flist:
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, low_memory=False, header=None)
    df1 = df.loc[~df[0].str.contains(pattern1, regex=False)]  # if you have a fixed string, regex=False will be much faster
```

Comment: could i request you to also upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should do the read only for the ones which passed the check (in if block), by doing this:

```
for files in os.listdir(outPath):
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
           for f in os.listdir(outPath):
```

The `if` statement went useless. Thus, you should just do:

```
for f in os.listdir(outPath):
    if f.endswith(".txt"):
         df1=pd.read_csv(f,header=None)
```

By doing this, you will only read csv from the `txt` files, not another random files.